# How to format a long Ansible command module task over multiple lines?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to format following command tasks over multiple lines.

```
tasks:
    ...
    - name: Run the python file
      command: "{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}/bin/pythonfile.py \"{{ cmd_status.stdout }}\" {{ test_number }}"
```

Works without formatting. `pythonfile` is executed properly. I tried formatting with `>`:

```
tasks:
    ...
    - name: Run the python file
      command: >
        "{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}/bin/pythonfile.py \"{{ cmd_status.stdout }}\" {{ test_number }}"
```

and it gives:

> "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",

```
Debug:
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "\"/home/bin/pythonfile.py
```

Any suggestions on formatting the command line over multiple lines.

Comment: The problem is still visible in the `-vvv` results, but the value is stripped. For clarity you should include the whole `_raw_params`.

Comment: YAML has good options for this. It's not specific to Ansible. [YAML Multiline](https://yaml-multiline.info/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply drop the surrounding quotes:

```
command: >
  {{ lookup('env','HOME') }}/bin/pythonfile.py "{{ cmd_status.stdout }}" {{ test_number }}
```

Otherwise the whole string (including spaces and arguments) is considered to be the name of the executable to run (notice `\"` surrounding the whole line in the debug invocation string).

When you write it in a single line, the gets first interpreted and stripped by YAML parser.